# Change webkit-scrollbar-track-piece's color when webkit-scrollbar-thumb is hovered?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have the following CSS rule:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

I want to also decorate webkit-scrollbar-track-piece when webkit-scrollbar-thumb is hovered. Something like:

```
//  Doesn't work:
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Is this possible with just CSS using another expression that I'm not aware of? Or is this not possible to do currently?

Answer (score 0):

2019 - This works for me (in Chrome at least) to lighten scrollbars on hover:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200,.1) !important;
}
```

or for a particular class:

```
.fooClass:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200,.1) !important;
}
```

(You can change the color/opacity ...)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover + ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

or

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover ~ ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Comment: No go on either of them, unfortunately. Good idea though -- I wonder if there are any other selectors other than sibling/adjacent